# jQuery - Combobox that allows inserting text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

I'm looking for a combobox that would allow the user to search through an array of predefined options but, depsite that, the user is allowed to write custom text in the combobox and that text shuldn't be discarded.

I've googled out tons of cool-looking full-featured combobox, but everyone was deleting the text user inserted if it didn't match any predefined option.

I've already tried these plugins:

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

http://www.igniteui.com/combo/selection-and-checkboxes

none of those was doing what I wanted.

Just to make sure my question is clear, look at this example: http://www.igniteui.com/combo/selection-and-checkboxes . There, if you type "Violet" in the combobox under "**Drop Down on Focus, Single Selection**" it will be discarted, but I want to keep that text, in order to allow the user to insert new colors.

I don't think I'm the only one on this planet who has ever faced this problem, and I'm really sure that somewhere there's already a ready solution, but google is hiding it from me.

PS: I already have jQuery in my project, so I prefer a jQuery solution insted of  Bootstrap/angularJS.

Comment: You want to do something like **Multiple Selection (Hold Ctrl Key to Select Multiple Items)** in your link?

Comment: Nope, I want to insert "Violet" on **Drop Down on Focus, Single Selection** and, when I click away, what I typed still has to be there (now it disappears because it's not in the list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are willing to include it in your project, jQuery UI's [autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) can provide that functionality ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GmMj6/)):

For displaying the "combobox" simply set minLength to 0 and call search on focus (see [autocomlete API doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search)).

```
 $(function() {
   var availableColors = [
     "red",
     "green",
     "blue"
   ];

  $( "#colors" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableColors, 
    minLength:0, 
    delay:0        
  });

  $('#colors').focus(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete('search');
  });
});
```

Comment: Well, it's not a combobox but it still does the trick. Thank you much! :)